# Plant Identification: White Mushroom or Fungus found in Indiana

Tags: mushrooms, fungi-identification

I believe it to be a [polypore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypore), but was unable to identify the exact type.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those look like [oyster mushrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleurotus_ostreatus). They are the right size and color and have the right type of gills.

> Pleurotus ostreatus, is a common edible known for its oyster-shaped cap. One of the first things you should look for when trying to identify this mushroom is the presence of decurrent gills.
>
> Decurrent means that the gills are attached to and run directly down the stem. Take a look at the close up to the right. Can you see how they run into and down the stem?

[Oyster Mushroom Identification](https://www.mushroom-appreciation.com/oyster-mushroom.html#sthash.QC6ks2yh.dpbs) (Definitely check the pictures out as they look very close to yours.)

For more sources with very close pictures see,

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pleurotus_ostreatus
- https://foodal.com/knowledge/paleo/morels-and-wild-mushrooms/
- https://www.mnn.com/your-home/organic-farming-gardening/stories/wild-mushrooms-what-to-eat-what-to-avoid
- https://www.motherearthnews.com/real-food/foraging-for-oyster-mushrooms-zbcz1411

Do note that while oyster mushrooms are edible, eating the wrong mushrooms can kill you so I would take these to a local to be absolutely certain.

Comment: I believe you're right. The bottom "gills" look spot on, and from the top view they look just like the pictures provided in your source. Also, I don't plan on eating them, at least not this time. Thank you!